# Dividir array em partes com n elementos sem destruir original

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu recebo o resultado do backend que é um array de objetos, e quero mostrar os resultados em páginas com um máximo de resultados escolhido pelo usuário por um select.
A minha função de dividir em páginas tá assim:

```
function sliceLista(tipo, numExibirRegistros) { //Função de dividir resultados em páginas
    listar.length = 0;
    if (tipo == "com") {
        let i = 0
        while (i < todasTeses.com.length) {
            listar.push(todasTeses.com.slice(i, (i+numExibirRegistros)));
            i += numExibirRegistros;
        }
    } else if (tipo == "sem") {
        let i = 0
        while (i < todasTeses.sem.length) {
            listar.push(todasTeses.sem.slice(i, (i+numExibirRegistros)));
            i += numExibirRegistros;
        }
    }
}
```

o problema que está acontecendo é que só a primeira "página" está vindo com o número correto de resultados, e a segunda está pegando todo o resto.

Edit: A função de dividir que estou usando parece ser igual a outras sugeridas(caso não seja favor me explicar onde). O problema que estou tendo é que só o primeiro slice pega a quantidade correta, o segundo slice pega todo o resto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function paginate(array, page_size, page_number) {
      return array.slice((page_number - 1) * page_size, page_number * page_size);
}

const array = [{ name: "Julio" }, { name: "Giuliano" }]

console.log(paginate(array, 1, 1))
```

seu array de objetos:

```
const array = [{ name: "Julio" }, { name: "Giuliano" }]
```

função de paginação

```
function paginate(array, page_size, page_number) {
  return array.slice((page_number - 1) * page_size, page_number * page_size);
}
```

onde `page_size` é o tamanho do `array` que você quer mostrar (1, 2, 100 etc) e `page_number` é o número em que vc vai estar. ex se o `array` tem 100 itens e você colocou um tamanho de 50, se seu page number for 1, você vai acessar os 50 primeiros itens, se for 2 será os 50 seguintes itens.

Comment: Funcionou para retornar os resultados por página corretamente, obrigado.